# Ado.net Update Command is successful but database is not updated

Tags: ado.net, sql-update

The following code executes successfully and the return value of cmd.ExecuteNonQuery returns 1 indicating the row was successfully updated but the database is not truly updated. How could that be? I'm using sqlserver2008.

```
public string updatePost(string id, string head, string body)
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
    string cmdStr = "update News set Header = '"+head+"' , [Text] = '"+body+"' where Id = "+int.Parse(id)+"";
    string msg = String.Empty;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, connection);
        int effected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        msg += "The 'News Post - id:"+id+"'  was successfully updated. Rows effected:"+effected+"";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        msg = "The attempt to update the 'News Post - id'" + id + " failed with message: " + ex.Message; 
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }

    return msg;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this fixes some problems (like sql-injection), perhaps also your update issue:

```
public string UpdatePost(string id, string head, string body)
{
    string msg = "";
    string cmdStr = "update News set Header = @header, [Text] = @body where Id = @id";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@header", head);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body", body);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(id));

                int effected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                msg += "The 'News Post - id:" + id + "'  was successfully updated. Rows effected:" + effected + "";
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = "The attempt to update the 'News Post - id'" + id + " failed with message: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

    return msg;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I've discovered that nothing is wrong with my c# code. The problem I was having was with javascript jquery. I solved the problem and the database is being updated. Truly the database had always been updating but the new data wasn't being included in the update. Thank you. Your code is a viable alternative.